# How does one share stuff on Google+ using buttons like the ones Facebook / Twitter have?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

There are Facebook share button and Twitter share buttons, is there one such button for Google+? The +1 button doesn't seem to be a Google+ share button, it just seems to be a social search recommendation.

Comment: I have not yet seen any "share on Google+" code out there, either to embed in a website or as a bookmarklet. There are several Chrome extensions that will do that, though. One I like is called "Surplus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +1 button is now (or soon) set to allow for sharing on Google+.

Here's a quote from [SilconFilter](http://siliconfilter.com/the-1-button-just-got-useful-now-lets-you-share-content-on-google/):

> Starting today [August 24], though, the +1 button will finally become
>   useful. Over the next few days, Google will roll out an updated
>   version of the button that will allow users to use it to share content
>   with their circles on Google+.  The button will also automatically add
>   text snippets and images from any page you want to share, similar to
>   the feature Google introduced on Google Books earlier this month.

I'm in the preview program, so my account is already rolled out. I just used it and it works as advertised.

Comment: Yes I'm a part of the preview program too and it does work as advertised.

Comment: Note: As of 11/7/2011, the Google Reader +1 icon doesn't make the +1 actual posts. It only puts the +1s into your Profile->+1's tab. (I think +1 icons placed by web site owners do create +1s as posts; though I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 8):

Google +1 is equivalent to the Facebook and Twitter share buttons. When you click +1 on a post, it's the same thing as when you share a link through the other web services.

The thing you have to note is that it won't show if you're using the +1 from inside a post on a Google+ Circle. It will show if you click it from a website or Google search. That's the public/private distinction.

> #### [About the +1 button](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1207011&answer=1047397)
>
> Use the +1 button to publicly show what you like, agree with, or recommend on the web. The +1 button can appear in a variety of places, both on Google and on sites across the web

When you're logged into Google+ you'll see a tab labelled **+1's**. This collects those pages and such around the Internet where you've clicked that +1 button on.

You can share this tab with the public and its contents.

To [change your tab settings](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1355574&answer=1297136) to allow public viewing of your +1 items:

1. Sign in to Google+
2. Click the Profile icon at the top of the page
3. Click **Edit profile**
4. Click the tab you'd like to edit
5. Choose the appropriate tab visibility setting
6. Click **Save.**

Comment: but that doesn't show up on the main tab, I guess the buttons will start coming up once google releases an API for google plus

Comment: The +1s don't show up on the main tab or the shared items doesn't show? @fre

Comment: The +1s don't show up on the main tab

Comment: There is an important distinction between Google+ and +1. This does not appear to be recognised in Eight Days' response, but has been noted by Nitigya. Google takes the blame for giving confusingly similar names to two services.

Comment: This is no longer strictly true. You can now "share" from the +1 button.

Answer (score 1):

The +1 button is not actually for sharing stuff on Google+. It is just like Facebook's 'Like' button but not the 'Share' button. The +1 button adds a sort of recommendation from you as a user, which helps in Google Search by showing up higher in search results especially when you and your friends are logged in to Google. I basically suggest that your friend has +1d it, so the search result may be relevant for you as well.

Comment: This is no longer true. You can now share what you've +1'd (assuming the site's code is up-to-date).

Answer (score -1):

I found code for a Google+ Share button here:
http://www.stateofsearch.com/share-on-google-plus-any-website/